# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, rendering, use-effect

I am developing a React app and I don't know how to solve this error. I'm pretty sure it's from my useEffect function, but I can't figure out what's wrong. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

```
const CourseTypeFour = ({ data, classes, bgWhite }) => {
   let { id } = data;
   const [courseObject, setCourseObject] = useState({});

   useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/courses/${id}`).then((response) => {
          setCourseObject(response.data);
        });
    },[id]);

   return (
      ...
   )
}
export default CourseTypeFour;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't in this part of the code. In error, you can see that problem is when you try to use the `toString` method on a variable that is `undefined`. Try to find part of the code where you use the `toString` method, and before it execute the `console.log` function with this variable to see what is inside.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I tested something a while ago and had completely forgotten about it. Now it works. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Could you tag my answer as correct answer? 